# inner join query returns diffrent values

Tags: sql, join

I'm new to SQL and I'm learning with Customers table in W3schools and it requests to select all customers that are from the same countries as the suppliers:

**SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Suppliers);**

[query result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXsta.png)

I am trying with a different query using JOIN for that question:

**select * from customers
inner join suppliers
on customers.country = suppliers.country**

[query result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBoaw.png)

And it got different query results. Could not figure out what's wrong here. Please advise.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the differences of which you speak.

Comment: Sure! I have been updated the question and attached 2 query result screenshots.

Comment: What is your question? If you expect these to be the same, say why, referencing an authoritative source. Otherwise an answer is just, because that's how SQL is defined. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: My comments & actions are neutral & helpful. [help] Also see the voting arrow mouseover texts. Also the first sentence of my first comment. Also when your question is pinned down we can clearly expect it to be a beginner's faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. PS You can edit to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries are not synonymous.

The first query with `IN` clause returns rows based on a boolean `True`/`False` condition. It can only reduce number of rows. It cannot add rows or add columns. Even if multiple countries show up in either table, it checks if each customer country shows up *at least once* in any row of suppliers with same country. If `True`, rows are kept. To sum up, query's dimensions include:

- ROWS: Returns filtered rows for at least one country pair match
- COLUMNS: Returns only customers columns

The second query with `INNER JOIN` now merges in a new data source (supplier table) that increases both rows and columns. This time *every* matching customer country to supplier country is returned. So instead of checking if at least one match exists, now *all* pairwise matches are returned. To sum up, query's dimensions include:

- ROWS: Returns rows of all pairwise country matches between both tables
- COLUMNS: Returns all customers and all suppliers columns

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it more thoroughly now.

Answer (score 2):

Your queries have different meanings.

In the first you are basically filtering out all customers for which the country is in supplier. Basically you check that the country field of the customer is in the list of countries of the subquery (SELECT COUNTRY FROM Suppliers)

In the second however, you join customers with the suppliers countries. Basically if two suppliers have the same country as a customer, you result will return your customer twice.

Let me know if somethings not clear.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your well explained answer! That means I should not use join for that question then.